# Adding telerik reference and using telerik controls in view page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik, telerik-mvc

i want to add telerik.dll reference to the application and use the telrik controls in my application. i added the reference and added namespace in web.config file as 
'add namespace="Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI"' but i am not getting HTML.Telerik(). extensions. please help me.

wheather i need to add any script reference?????

Comment: If your View file was open when adding namespace to web.config , you should close and reopen it.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Getting Started`](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/introduction) page explains in details what you need to do step by step. Also if you added the namespace to your `~/Views/web.config` you might need to close and reopen the corresponding view in VS for the changes to take effect.